# exporting web page to pdf using asp.net

Tags: c#

I have a web page containing employee data from employee table. I called GetEmployeeDetails() function to get the details. I have service for GetEmployeeDetails(). I Want to explore this data to PDF. How to call GetEmployeeDetails() function?
I defined fileUploadLoc in webConfig.
I have following code. I dont know how to call That service function.

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 10, 25, 10);
DirectoryInfo destination = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileUploadLoc));
 Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileUploadLoc ));
  destination = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileUploadLoc ));
   destination.Create();
   PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfWriter.Open();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    ArrayList htmlList =     iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null);
     foreach (IElement el in htmlList)
       {
          pdfWriter.Add(el);

        }
     pdfDoc.Close();
```

I found solution:

```
DataSet obj = new DataSet();
obj = objServiceClient.GetEmployeeList();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (obj.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
   {
       sb.Append("<html>");
       sb.Append("<head>");
       sb.Append("</head>");
       sb.Append("<body >");
       sb.Append("</body >");
       sb.Append("</html >");

    }
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
ArrayList objects = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, styles);

   for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; k++)
      {
         pdfDoc.Add((IElement)objects[k]);
      }
```

I have problem with tag `<hr>`.Its not  displaying horizontal line.  And For `<table>`  "border" is not displaying. Please help me out.

Comment: What you want to export, Page or only EmployeeDetails content?

Comment: Employee Details.                                                                             DataSet dsObj = objServiceClient.GetEmployeeList();                                       This is how i called Sevice method.